# As for paperclip to change the save path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have a monolith.
Monolith consists of two applications `app1` and `app2`.
The file is saved in `app1`, but display `(@ticket.document.url)` in `app2`.

`@ticket.document.url` (in `app2`) will display the path `app2_root/public/system/path/to/file`, but the file is in `app1_root/public/system/path/to/file`

How to change the save path set by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement an API, if you need programatically calculated data from another app.

I would probably go ahead and do something like this in app 1:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: {ticket: {document_url: @ticket.documment.url}} }
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

Then in app 2:

```
json_string = open("https://www.app1.com/tickets/1.json") { |io| io.read }
json = JSON.parse(json_string)
document_url = json.fetch("ticket").fetch("document_url")
```

Comment: I made the folder `public/system` total (symlink) and it worked.